# Is cannibalism part of mainstream food-chain?

Tags: ecology, food, ethology, food-web

There are some species who sometimes eat their own kinds. Is this cannibalism considered their regular food? Do the link in food-chain for those animals make a loop on themselves?

Can this statement: "Food chains are found within the population of a species." be held true?

Disclosure: The above statement was part of a question that asked to identify the correct among statements. I tried to find relevant content in books and internet but couldn't find any. I'm not trying to get my assignment solved, but I want opinion on cannibalism and it's impact on food chains.

Comment: *A food chain is a linear network of links in a food web* [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_chain). If you consider species as the nodes of the network, cannibalism could be represented as an edge that connects the species whit itself. This makes the network non-linear, So I suggest to used `food web` instead of `food chain` I think your statement can be true if you consider individuals of a given cannibalistic species as the nodes of your network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannibalism can be found across most animal groups. For some groups of organisms (e.g., spiders, fishes) cannibalism can be common within a single generation. Sometimes it will be between siblings, but more often with other members of their species.

As @heracho pointed out, from a network/food web/flow-diagram perspective, yes, cannibalism is repressed as a negative feedback loop on itself.

Evaluating the statement: "Food chains are found within the population of a species," I interpret is as, within species, there are subgroups that consume subgroups, that consume subgroups. You'd need at least 3 levels for it to be considered a chain (i.e., you don't have a chain with two species/a single link). Cannibalism would be a single link/two species, and not considered a chain. As to whether or not chains exist within a species, I suspect it is not common if it exists at all. If it did, I would guess it'd be found in a group like fishes where prey are often size dependent.